# Using ssh -t works to connect over a Jump Host but ssh -W does not work

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I'm trying to connect my computer `LocalClient` to `RemoteHost` via a `JumpHost` that I have no control over. I have complete control of the `client` and `RemoteHost` (admin privileges)

I can connect to the `RemoteHost` from `LocalClient` perfectly via ssh as:

`ssh -tX relayUserName@JumpHost remoteUser@RemoteHostIP`

My ~/.ssh/config file has the config as:

```
Host RemoteHost
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p JumpHost
```

Now, if I try to tunnel through the `RemoteHost`, I get an error as:

```
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
```

Using `ssh -v`, I get a little more information

```
Authenticated to <JumpHost> ([JumpHostIP]:22).
debug1: channel_connect_stdio_fwd RemoteHostIP:22
debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/ssh-tunneling-error-channel-1-open-failed-administratively-prohibited-open), I've checked the values of `sshd_config` in `/etc/ssh/` on `RemoteHost` and (manually) set

`AllowTcpForwarding yes`

The problem still persists and I don't know what else to try.

#### Details:

- OS: `RemoteHost` and `LocalClient` : Kubuntu 18.04 LTS
- ssh versions (arrived via ssh -v ) : `RemoteHost` and `LocalClient`: `OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017`
- ssh version: `JumpHost` (arrived via ssh -v debug1):

```
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
```

---

As a side note, I need to tunnel to the `RemoteHost` to access a Jupyter Lab instance running with `--no-browser --port=8889` and forward it to my `LocalClient`'s port 8888 for accessing my experiments remotely via a browser on `localhost:8888`